# How to get S3 file path from URI?

Tags: 8

So inside my hook function I have URI of some file and I need to find it's S3 path (using s3fs module). How can I do that, to avoid manual string manipulation? Is there some helper function?

I found convertUriToKeyedPath() of S3fsStream class but it's protected and also it says "Converts a Drupal URI path into what is expected to be stored in S3" and that "expect is potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Use file_url_generator service:

```
$uri = 's3://bucket/file.ext';
$url = \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generateAbsoluteString($uri);
```

An old way (deprecated as of 9.3):

```
$http_url = file_create_url($uri);
```

Comment: No, it's opposite. I have drupal URI of file and I need to find S3 path.